# Comparing two dates in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, date, string-comparison

I know this could be a basic question but i have been stuck on this for hours. What i am trying to do is a comparing two dates in JSP and if the following equals each other do the follow.

```
    <%
        if(!viewBean.isHiddenEndDate())
        {
            (reportVO.getEndDate().getYear() == 9999 && reportVO.getEndDate().getMonth() == 12 && reportVO.getEndDate().getDate() == 31);
    %>
        <td headers="EndDate<%=localizationHelper.getContentString(reportVO.getLocalizedTypeLabel())%>">"Until terminated"</td>
    <%  }else{ %>
        <td headers="EndDate"><%=localizationHelper.formatDate(reportVO.getEndDate())%></td>
    <%
    }
    %>
```

However when i do this, mySyntax error, insert `AssignmentOperator Expression` to complete Assignment and Syntax error, insert `;` to complete BlockStatements.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is expecting something like `boolean flag =` to the left of the line `(reportVO.getEndDate().getYear() == 9999 && reportVO.getEndDate().getMonth() == 12 && reportVO.getEndDate().getDate() == 31);`   Hence the error about completing the Assignment Operator Expression.